# Regular expression with special characters and a specific string

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression for a string of maximum length 12.

The string is following this pattern:  `####{value}#####`

where `#` could be `$`, `%`, `&`, `*` and `\n` or space. And `{value}` is a constant string that will always be present. The number of `#` will vary.

**For example**

1. `####{value}`
2. `###{value}#`
3. `##{value}##`
4. `#{value}###`
5. `{value}`
   `####` (with newline)

**I came up with**

```
/^([\*#$%&\s]+{value}+[\*#$%&\s]){0, 12}$/
```

but it's not working.

Comment: With the help of @Tim [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74456246/19914748), this is working for me. 

`code` /^(?!.{13})[*#$%&\s]*{value}[*#$%&\s]*$/;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a positive lookahead to limit the length to a maximum of 12 characters.

```
^(?!.{13})[*#$%&\s]*.+[*#$%&\s]*$
```

You may sandwich any value you wish between the two character classes of symbols.